# Dwarf raising a battalion of dinosaurs

Tags: technology, warfare, science-fiction, dinosaurs, creature-design

Set in alternate parallel universe where reality mirror ours with one big exception, the cunning dwarfs. The male adult is less than the length of an iPad but weights 50Kg, their technology is far superior than us but we outnumbered them by a factor of 10,000,000,000:1.

**Scenario**

Set in the 21st century A.D. the dwarf already solved the dark matter and dark energy issue and also harnessing energy from quarks fusion/fission process taping into the strong nuclear force and detonate the world first quarks bomb in an underground testing facility on Mars. They have invented an ingenious way of exploiting the laws of physics governing quantum gravity and managed to weave all fundamental forces together to open a boom tube into the past and successfully fetch a family of Diplodocus into the present in order to spite human kind.

**Questions**

My question is if the dwarfs now possesses an army of dinosaurs spanning from Jurassic to the Triassic period, how can human wage war against these prehistoric creature assuming the dwarf already solved the "jet lag" and adaptability issue for these creature?

**Conditions**

The victory condition is to enslave the dinosaurs and feed the dwarf to the carnivorous, vice versa will spell our demise (defeat is unacceptable).

**Notes**

Dwarf being more intelligent than us will teleport millions of dinosaurs regardless of size, diet, wings, etc fit tem with breathing apparatus at all kinds of power plants, military HQ, air bases, naval yards, military barracks, arsenals, communication towers and underground bunkers simultaneously and instantaneously. (1 wave per hour each facility will be swarmed with max. capped at 1 thousand dinosaurs per day.)

The dwarf will not use their tech directly against us unless all of our resistances failed meaning all of our military capabilities are compromised and the dwarf will put the remaining human populations out of its misery.

The dwarf plans to overrun each military facility with thousands of dinosaurs each equipped with an ambulatory device with two pronged attack from the inside out and encircling the entire premises.

Submarine will be chased by hundreds of Mosasaurus.

Air fields are infested with swarms of prehistoric insects and thousands of Pterosaurs ambushing landing or refuelling aircraft.

Comment: Reality mirrors ours, except for, well you know.. the *dwarves and dinosaurs*.  O_O

Comment: More than the dinosaurs, I would be worried about the ability of such "quantum technology" to send in a termonuclear device or, alternatively, send an entire city deep into the Sun.

Comment: A parallel universe similar to ours, exept that there are dwarves that we outnumber 10 billion to one.  I.e. there exists less than 10 such dwarves.

Comment: @Taemyr yes as my OP states we really outnumbered them hee hee

Comment: okay this is hard mode unless all dwarves drop dead else attacks continue.

Comment: "...but we outnumbered them by a factor of 10,000,000,000:1."  Soo.. there's like.. one of them?

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, kindly focus on surviving the onslaught and let the poor fellow go, please do not try to piss schrodinger dwarf!

Comment: @Neil I assumed this was a "rough estimate" aka, wild assed guess.  So I allowed for up to two orders of magnitude error.  So maybe as much as ten dwarves.

Comment: @Taemyr Then you should remove a zero.  Not sure if there are 10 billion people on the planet.

Comment: @Neil There isn't, but it's more than (9.5)^10.

Comment: @Taemyr it could be late 21st century I'm pretty sure China might abandon its one child policy by then.

Comment: @user6760 Late 21st century is very different from early 21st, Chine not having a one child policy is peanuts compared to all the other ways things will be different.  I have in all my answers assumed early 21st century(ie. now), rather than late 21st century.  -  We can make a reasonably complete description of human tech today, if instead it's in 50 years we have to make guesses that we are very unlikely to get correctly.

Comment: 1000 dinosaurs per facility per day? Or 1000 dinos per day total? Also, could you please clarify what you mean by ambulatory devices? Lastly, are these dinos getting teleported back to Mars after the raid?

Comment: @AmbarishSathianathan for example the dwarf will teleport 100 dinosaurs into the military HQ and will repeatedly send another 100 more every hour but the maximum head counts of surviving dinosaurs will not exceed 1000 per day. These devices is for the dinosaur to adapt to our environment absolutely no combat capabilities. Actually no they are deployed for good and they don't come from Mars.

Comment: Dinos dont **fit** inside a military HQ.  They are big things.

Comment: 1. Develop insane technology 2. Bring back extinct animals 3. ??? 4. Kill all humans

Comment: @user6760 you've made a lot of edits to this question, and it looks like some of them may have interfered with answers that were already posted.  Once a question has answers we avoid edits to the question that invalidate those answers.  I see that the community has put this question on hold; if you edit to try to get it reopened, please keep the existing answers in mind.

Comment: @Monica Cellio my earlier revisions are tailored to suit commentators, my future edits will factors in those existing answers in case I am appealing to reopen this question.

Answer (score 2):

## Shoot them

No really. A dinosaur is no match for any kind of reasonably powerful gun. Even hand-held weapons made for that goal can bring them down, let alone anything vehicle or aircraft mounted.

## Tranqualisers

If you really *must* enslave the dinosaurs for your zoo or something, use tranq-darts. We have no trouble dropping elephants with them, so just increase the dosage a few steps if it's a big one and bring down the dinosaurs.

If they're aggressive, carnivorous, or otherwise dangerous, do it from a helicopter so they can't reach.

At the end of the day, they are just animals. When you learn to wage war on tanks and aircraft, animals sort of stop being dangerous.

Comment: Most dinosaurs where smaller than elephats, so dosage might not need to be increased.  Also where you say carnivorous I would say agressive. Herbivores can easily be as dangerous as carnivors.

Comment: Also and I relize that this is beyond what OP asks however the problem in the scenario described is the technology of the dwarves, rather than the dinosaurs.

Comment: @Taemyr The question is, "How can human wage war against these prehistoric creature assuming the dwarf already solved the "jet lag" and adaptability issue for these creature?"  I take that to mean, "How do we fight dinosaurs?"

Comment: @Neil I agree and I believe I stated as much in the comment.  However if I actually was a general in the sitation described I would be far more worried about how the dwarves would stop my helicopters that where out dino hunting than how to actually round up the dinosaurs.  We have proven to be fairly good hunters, but are rather untested as anti-mages.

Comment: @Taemyr Good point, though this entire scenario is a little impossible to imagine.  I do agree with you that the biggest threat would be the dwarves, not the dinosaurs, which are perhaps more of a distraction than anything else.

Comment: Guys my OP specifically states adaptability so these dinosaurs relies on dwarf tech heavily to accustom to our air and the trip through time, so can we exterminate the dwarf there are only a handful targets as pointed out by Taenyr shouldn't be difficult at all.

Comment: Are these dinosaurs tinkered with beyond being able to operate under our oxygen levels? If so, the OP should explain more what differentiates these beasts from the common giant lizards. As it stands, dinosaurs are simply not a threat on a military level.

Comment: okay I'll revise my OP to give humanity a fighting chance.

Comment: With the revised OP, the humans will still round up the dinosaurs pretty easily. They are simply no match for heavy weapons and armored vehicles. There's a reason we drop bombs on fortifications instead of dangerous animals with parachutes. Animals simply aren't threatening enough.

Comment: Sort of hard to defend against several large dinosaurs instantly teleporting into a military base.  I don't doubt there would be casualties, but ultimately dinosaurs are like animals in a sense.  If you teleported 20 hippopotamuses in a military base, would there be casualties?  Yes.  Would they be unstoppable?  Not hardly.  Most would likely do nothing except find a place to hide in this new and terrifying environment.

Comment: @Neil and I think that more of the aggressive ones will attack each other.

Comment: Yup - barring some unmentioned mind control, the dinos likely ignore the people on the base.  The plant eaters eat the shrubbery, the meat eaters hunt the plant eaters.  Barring a few losses to bad luck, the troops gather in a hangar and prepare to kill or herd the dinos out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

## A Bad time to be in the military

If there is no warning the first wave would be a success.

Most active military complexes have the ability to fend of dinosaurs.  However they do not have the planning or on-alert capability to deal with thousands of aggresive beasts being teleported inside the periphery.  This means that most army installations will be taken out in the first wave, casualities in bases that do get taken out could be high, my guess would be 60-80%.

Naval bases and Airbases will to even poorer.

Every submarine is going to be neutralised, they just don't have any weapons to take out that number of creatures.

Surface naval vessels will surivive the first wave if they have, or are in a squadron that has, anti-submarine armaments.  However they will not survive several waves as they will run out of ammunition.

## Now what

The dwarves have better have a good followup plan.

As stated most army bases and essentially all air bases gets taken out in the first attack.  However further attacks on bases on land is going to be futile.

On the sea, human military might is doomed - we are simply unable to resupply our ships sufficiently to make a difference.

In the first attacks the dwarves have killed some million human soldiers, and taken out trillions of dollars worth of military equipment.  However there is still billions of humans left.  And a lot of weapons.  No dino is ever going to be a match for a human with a high powered rifle.

Rather than sending several waves against military bases a better option for the dwarves is to send one wave against the military.  Then switch to civilian targets.  Trash any communication equpment, then infrastructure, then industry.  Then start mopping up human surviors.

This would be bad for us, a lot of people would die and the economy would take decades to recover.  However this is a poor way to exterminate humankind, wild beasts are simply not that big a threat.

## Human countermeasures

Ultimately the dino attacks becomes a numbers game.  Some of the attacks will have some sucess. - A T-Rex teleporting in, falling over a truck, and destroying that truck counts as a sucess here.  Humankind will be able to replace some losses.  If the dino's destroy more than the humankind replaces they win if they are able to continue indefinitly.  If the humans are able to keep replacing the losses then they "win", as they can survive the onslaught indefinitly.  See [tonnage war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonnage_war) for real life examples of how these kinds of situations play out in real life.

If the humans are unable to replace losses fast enough or they want to stop worrying about several tons of angry dinosaurs suddenly popping into existence next to them they need to attack either the dwarves or the time travel devices directly.  Your post does not give any direct indication of the feasibility of this, except that you place their experimental base on mars.  If the dwarves are on Mars they are beyond the reach of human military might for the forseeable future. - We might be able to send manned expeditions to mars, but not expeditions that can be expected to survive hostilities.

Comment: I've capped the attackers to 3 digits every day or any advise how to reduce difficulty further.

Comment: @user6760 That's not really the issue.  The first attack is going to be devestating, but subsequent waves are not.  Wild beasts remains a poor way to deal with a human infestation.  The problem is that if the dwarves can keep doing this forever this boils down to one of two things; Either some attack by the humans on the dwarves, which relies on the feasibility of such attacks - something you don't go into in your answer.  Or a number game where the humans needs to replace resources fast enough to make up for losses to teleporting dino.  I will edit my answers to expand on these.

Comment: "No dino is ever going to be a match for a human with a high powered rifle." Not to nitpick or anything, but if a T-rex is standing five feet away from a soldier with a .50-caliber rifle, I'm putting my money on the T-rex.

Comment: @Frostfyre Yes,  and this is an actual issue with my answer - not just you being nitpicky.  I quietly assume that the teleport is not accurate enough to make that happen regulary.  But there is so many ifs and buts here that dealing with them all would make the answer even more unreadable.

Comment: @Frostfyre Also, I state high velocity rifle, not heavy arms.  I am banking on 7.62 being capable of taking down a t-rex.  This is actually important, because there are far more assault rifles than MG's.  Especially outside of military arsenals.